# How do I stream audio from fb2k to android over wifi?

Tags: android, streaming, foobar2000

I want to stream whatever is playing on foobar to my android phone, over wifi. Or maybe I should just buy a bluetooth card for the PC.

Windows 7. Haven't tried anything at all yet. Sending the files seems absurdly cumbersome...

Comment: It would help to know a bit more. What is your operating system version (vista, 7, 8, 10)? What have you tried so far? Have you considered simply streaming the files to your android device and having the android device play them... and if so, why don't you want to do that? Be sure to edit and update your question with any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Sending and Receive Audio:

a. Install the app 'wireless speaker for android' - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vnd.wifi_audio&hl=pt_BR

b. Install this soft on your pc - http://wifiaudio.boards.net/thread/2/wifiaudio-support-links-download-application

The pc software will send all audio from your pc to your android and the android app will receive it and play it.

2. Control foobar from phone:

a. Install the android app 'foobar2000 controller' - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cav.foobar2000controller&hl=en_US

b. On the pc, inside foobar2000, install the component 'HTTP Control' - http://foobar2000controller.blogspot.com.es/p/how-to-start.html

Note:

Sending audio will be relatively easy. But the foobar controller will be tricky to setup. You will need time and patience, but once you have done that, its like having your entire hardisk in your phone. So its worth the trouble. Best of Luck.